# How to know if resistors are in series?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

According to Fundamentals of Electric Circuits, 6th edition, Alexander & Sadiku, p. 36

> Elements are in series when they are chain-connected or connected sequentially, end to end. For example, two elements are in series if they share one common node and no other element is connected to that
> common node.

Let us apply this definition to the above circuit. We can see that R1 and R2 are in series as the node B is common, and no other element is connected to that common node. Moreover, R2 and R3 are in series as the node C is common, and no other element is connected to that common node. As *all* of the current that enters through R1 also enters through R2, we can see that R1 and R3 are also in series. However, no no node is common between them. So, doesn't Sadiku's definition fail here?

Comment: Why are $R_1$ and $R_3$ in series due to common sense?

Comment: @KyleKanos edited

Comment: Well, at no point is there an escape for current, so you are interpreting it too finely.

Comment: Okay, what common node do $R_1$ and $R_3$ share?

Comment: @KyleKanos There is no common node between R1 and R3.

Comment: So if there's no common node, then they're not in series as per the definition given by Sadiku. Case closed.

Comment: @KyleKanos Yes, that much is obvious. However, R1 and R3 are *in* series. So, didn't Sadiku furnish a wrong definition?

Comment: Well they are not in series, so no Sadiku did *not* furnish a wrong definition. You may need to provide more explanation as to why you believe that any one of the following is/are true: a) $R_1$ and $R_3$ connected sequentially; b) they have a common node between them; c) there is no element connected between them.

Comment: I would say they were "in series" if _all_ of the current that flows through either one must also flow through the other. By that definition, each of the three resistors in your circuit diagram is "in series" with each of the other two.

Comment: In technical writing, a sentence that starts "For example..." is, as said, just an example. That sentence *is not* the definition.

Comment: Perhaps we could add to your definition of 'in series' that if $R_1$ is in series with $R_2$ and if $R_2$ is in series with $R_3$, then $R_1$ is in series with $R_3$ – and so on.

Comment: [Finding the equivalent resistance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238044/finding-the-equivalent-resistance/238102#238102)

Answer (score 1):

I can read the statement as the first sentence being the definition, and the second sentence as only an example where the connection between two elements is a node (wire of zero resistance).  R1, R2 and R3 meet the definition of elements in series as they are "chain connected or connected sequentially, end to end". Moreover, since no other elements branch off them, all the current entering R1 must exit R3.

Hope this helps.